# When does the Last accessed date of a user gets udated in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

**I want to know all the actions that will update the Last Accessed Date of a user in Azure DevOps.**

[image]

A few of them that I know of are mentioned below:

- Login to Azure DevOps
- Changing the access level of a user
- Commit by a user
- Triggering a CI/CD pipeline, etc.

Let's say a user has created a Service Connection using their PAT, does the Last Accessed Date of this user gets updated whenever this Service Connection is triggered?

Please correct me wherever I'm wrong.
Please provide more ways on how the Last Accessed Date of a user gets updated in Azure DevOps.
Any supporting information/links are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the **Users** page of an Azure DevOps organization, the **`Last Accessed`** date for a user will update generally when any of the following things occurs:

1. The user login to the organization.
2. Use the user's authorization information (i.e., **`PAT`**) to call Azure DevOps REST API or Azure DevOps CLI to access the resources in the organization.
3. On a client app, use the user's authorization information to connect and access resources in the organization. Push changes from local repos to remote Azure Repos can be considered as this situation.
4. On a service hook or web app, use the user's authorization information to connect and access resources in the organization. **`Service Connection`** can be considered as this situation.

In a summary, [the **`Last Accessed`** is the last date a user accessed any resources or services in an Azure DevOps organization. Accessing Azure DevOps includes using organization URL (**`dev.azure.com/org_name`** or **`org_name.visualstudio.com`**) directly and using resources or services indirectly.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-user-and-permissions-management?view=azure-devops#user-access)

[image]

---

Comment: @sunbogaa, I'd like to know whether the explanation of "**`Last Accessed`**" in my answer is helpful for you to understand it deeper.

Comment: I want to know if these are the only cases for Last Accessed Date.